# search with multiple field shows in url I want to replace all the params and value with a specific string

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I am new to Wordpress help me out 
my current page url

https://myurl.com/search/?title=&value1=&title2=value2&title3=&value3&title4=&value4&title5=&value5

What I want is this

https://myurl.com/search/value1/value2/value3?url_params

Comment: I would be genuinely surprised if this is easily possible: you're looking to replace a search string with a directory structure. It isn't a trivial change.

Comment: so you are saying that it not that easy so can you suggest any other way to simplify the above url because i am getting very long url and i need make it short.